# nginx location can't have both rewrite and proxy

Tags: nginx

location = /land {

```
    proxy_pass http://172.0.0.78:3033;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Android|iPhone|iPod|Symbian|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|Mobile|J2ME)") {
            root /home/xxx/;
            rewrite /(.*) /index.html;
            break;
    }
```

}

Excuse me, where is the above problem?
How should I modify it?

thks~

Answer (score 0):

It's always wise to separate proxied and static content:

```
location = /land {    
  if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Android|iPhone|iPod|Symbian|BlackBerry|Windows Phone|Mobile|J2ME)") {
    rewrite ^ /index.html last;
  }
  proxy_pass http://172.0.0.78:3033;
}

location = /index.html {
  root /home/xxx/;
}
```